# VSCode Issues: Works in Terminal but not in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bavZX.jpg

As you can see, the code works fine in Terminal but not in VSCode. I've been using Spyder and PyCharm but I want to use VSCode now. What am I missing?

Comment: I have tested you code in vscode and it's working fine. Are you sure that you run it with the correct version? Test it with "python --version".

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please do not post images of code, of error messages or of text in general. Select the text then use the copy-paste functionality provided by your OS and put the text as text in the question. If it is code then select it in the question editor and use the `{}` button to nicely format it as code.

Comment: you use Python 2.x to execute Python 3.x code

Comment: @rioV8 I tried choosing the python 2.x interpreters but they don't work either. Am I supposed to do something with environments?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Python runs when you type python on the command line? It should tell you on the terminal after typing python. As mentioned in the comments you may be running different versions of python.

Are you running virtual environments?  After opening VScode you can select which version of python to use. Open the View menu item and select the Command Palette. When command palette opens type python. A list of python commands will be listed. look for "Select interpreter".  This will open a scroll down pane with your options of python interpreters. Be sure to select an interpreter for the version of python you need.

Comment: python 3.7.6. There is a python 3.7.6 that matches but it's an anaconda3 environment.

Answer (score 0):

When you run code in VS code it sets the environment using the interpreter you have set. This seems to run into issues if the environment is already active.

Try deactivating your environment in VS code then click run (F5)